# how to change blackberry Z10 simulator to blackberry q10 simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

i have blackberry vmware fusion and blackberry Z10  simulator.
i need to test with my application blackberry bb Q10 simulator, how to change bb Z10 to  Q10  in mac operating system..

Comment: Have you installed the most current Simulator?  When the Simulator starts, do you see a prompt that gives the option of selecting a specific device?

Comment: s .. i got a  solution .but Q10 real device have keyboard with screen, i got screen only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install the most current Simulator.  You can get this from the Downloads section of the BB10 Developer web site:

[BB10 Developer Microsite](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/)

Once installed, start the Simulator.  Immediately it starts up, you will, in the 'console', get the option to choose which device you want to emulate.

Note that if you choose a keyboard device like the Q10, you may only see the 'screen' - you can use your PC's keyboard to emulate the keyboard.